# I want to calculate the seconds that have passed from the time an application closed/quit to the time it loads again. It seems like my formula is off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In Unity I am trying to calculate the seconds that has passed since the application has closed to find out how many coins the player has earned. I tested my code out but my formula seems of since its giving me different values than I expected.

```
public class CoinGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Upgradable building;
    [SerializeField] private int coinsPerHourBase = 200; // Default coins per hour
    [SerializeField] private int capacityBase = 1000;    // Default capacity

    private int buildingLevel, coinsPerHour, capacity;
    private float coinsAccumulated;

    public int BuildingLevel { get { return buildingLevel; } }
    public float CoinsAccumulated { get { return coinsAccumulated; } }

    private void Start()
    {
        SetBuildingLevel();
        SetCoinsPerHourAndCapacity(buildingLevel);
        coinsAccumulated += CoinsEarnedSincePlayerQuit();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Calculate and accumulate coins over time
        float generatedCoins = (coinsPerHour * (Time.deltaTime / 3600f));
        coinsAccumulated = Mathf.Clamp(coinsAccumulated + generatedCoins, 0, capacity);
        //Debug.Log(coinsAccumulated);
    }

    public void SetCoinsPerHourAndCapacity(int buildingLevel)
    {
        this.buildingLevel = buildingLevel;
        coinsPerHour = coinsPerHourBase * buildingLevel; // Scale based on building level
        capacity = capacityBase * buildingLevel;         // Scale capacity based on building level
    }

    // Gets current ugrade level in Upgradable Component
    public void SetBuildingLevel()
    {
        buildingLevel = building.CurrentUpgradeLevel;
        SetCoinsPerHourAndCapacity(buildingLevel);
    }

    // Returns coins earned since player quit the scene
    private float CoinsEarnedSincePlayerQuit ()
    {
        // Subtract time now to time that the app last quit
        System.TimeSpan secondsSinceQuit = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeQuitRecorder.instance.TimeQuit); 

        // Calculate coins earned since last quit
        float generatedCoins = coinsPerHour * ((float)secondsSinceQuit.TotalSeconds / 3600f);
        //

        // Clamp value to building capacity
        float coinsEarned = Mathf.Clamp(generatedCoins, 0, capacity);

        Debug.Log("Seconds: " + secondsSinceQuit.TotalSeconds);
        return coinsEarned;
    }
```

The CoinsEarnedSincePlayerQuit() method is in charge of calculating the time that has passed from Quitting the application and from the time it loads back up. It takes the quit time from the TimeQuitRecorder Singleton and it takes the load time from when this CoinGenerator has loaded.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeQuitRecorder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static TimeQuitRecorder instance;
    private static System.DateTime _timeQuit;
    PlayerData playerData;
    public System.DateTime TimeQuit{ get { return _timeQuit; } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }

        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        _timeQuit = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

The TimeQuitRecorder saves the Time when the application closes to a private variable _timeQuit which can then be accessed through TimeQuit.

I stopped the scene for about 2 mins then when I loaded it back it displayed 63826919893.997 instead of somewhere around the value of 120.

Comment: How is `TimeQuitRecorder.instance.TimeQuit` set?

Comment: `private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        _timeQuit = System.DateTime.Now;
    }`

then TimeQuit gets the value of _timeQuit

Comment: Do you save that to PlayerPrefs or something? You either have a math problem or there's something wrong with the time you're saving and loading. You need to explain enough of what you're doing for us to help you. Do some more debugging. Log the values you're using and add that data to the question along with relevant code.

Comment: Rather than relying on the timestamp for when the application closes (what happens if it crashes and you don't manage to record the time?) why not save the timestamp from the last time you calculated their earnings?

Comment: This is a viable suggestion. I'm gonna try doing that thanks @Xerillio

Comment: In general ... how is this stored persistent? Every time you open the app and the code (compiled solution) is loaded .. well all fields will be initialized from scratch ... without any persistent data storage your assignment in `OnApplicationQuit` is absolutely meaningless

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build a save system for the game but the easiest way to check how many seconds passed from the last time you closed the game is by using PlayerPrefs and TimeSpan (Don't use Unity Time) and any second to save the current time.

Good luck.

Comment: Is it possible to store DateTime values in a JSON file? I am using JSON to store some player data and I want to add the DateTime in it.

Comment: @ClarcJaeVirgilMagbujos show your code for that part ;) And if you want support across time zones better use a `DateTimeOffset` ;)